# Remove first 4 character in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ngfor

I Have below ngFor I want to remove first four character of `c.FilmCode`

```
 <li class="">
    <a [(ngModel)]="selectedmovies" ngDefaultControl name="" class="form-control" (click)="togglemovies()" id="cbocmovies" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">{{selectedmoviestext}}</a>
    <div [ngClass]="{toggleMovie:IsToggleMovie==true}" *ngIf="movies.length > 0">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li *ngFor="let c of movies" [value]="c.FilmCode" (click)="OnMoviesChange(c.FilmTitle,c.FilmCode)">{{c.FilmTitle}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Below is `ts` code

```
showmoviecombo(CinemaId) {
  this.common.createAPIService('api/cinemas/GetListByCinemaId?CinemaId=' + CinemaId, '').subscribe((result: any) => {
        this.movies = result;
        //this.movieids = this.movies.FilmCode;
        console.log(this.movieids);
  });
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Use this `"your_string_here".substring(4);` or you can use pipe for this??

Comment: Yes..Done..It worked..substring

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **Slice** for removing the first four character

```
<li class="">
<a [(ngModel)]="selectedmovies" ngDefaultControl name="" class="form-control" (click)="togglemovies()" id="cbocmovies" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">{{selectedmoviestext}}</a>
<div [ngClass]="{toggleMovie:IsToggleMovie==true}" *ngIf="movies.length > 0">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li *ngFor="let c of movies" [value]="c.FilmCode" (click)="OnMoviesChange(c.FilmTitle,c.FilmCode)">{{c.FilmTitle.slice(4)}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` on your string value method

```
 <li class="">
    <a [(ngModel)]="selectedmovies" ngDefaultControl name="" class="form-control" (click)="togglemovies()" id="cbocmovies" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">{{selectedmoviestext}}</a>
    <div [ngClass]="{toggleMovie:IsToggleMovie==true}" *ngIf="movies.length > 0">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li *ngFor="let c of movies" [value]="c.FilmCode" (click)="OnMoviesChange(c.FilmTitle,c.FilmCode)">{{c.FilmTitle?.substring(4)}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```